# Monad with no wrapped value?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

Most of the monad explanations use examples where the monad wraps a value. E.g. `Maybe a`, where the `a` type variable is what's wrapped. But I'm wondering about monads that never wrap anything.

For a contrived example, suppose I have a real-world robot that can be controlled, but has no sensors. Maybe I'd like to control it like this:

```
robotMovementScript :: RobotMonad ()
robotMovementScript = do
  moveLeft 10
  moveForward 25
  rotate 180

main :: IO ()
main = 
  liftIO $ runRobot robotMovementScript connectToRobot
```

In our imaginary API, `connectToRobot` returns some kind of handle to the physical device. This connection becomes the "context" of the `RobotMonad`. Because our connection to the robot can never send a value back to us, the monad's concrete type is always `RobotMonad ()`.

Some questions:

1. Does my contrived example seem right?
2. Am I understanding the idea of a monad's "context" correctly? Am I correct to describe the robot's connection as the context?
3. Does it make sense to have a monad--such as `RobotMonad`--that *never* wraps a value? Or is this contrary to the basic concept of monads?
4. Are monoids a better fit for this kind of application? I can imagine concatenating robot control actions with `<>`. Though `do` notation seems more readable.
5. In the monad's definition, would/could there be something that ensures the type is always `RobotMonad ()`?

I've looked at `Data.Binary.Put` as an example. It appears to be similar (or maybe identical?) to what I'm thinking of. But it also [involves the Writer monad and the Builder monoid](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.4.3.1/docs/Data-Binary-Put.html#t%3aPutM). Considering those added wrinkles and my current skill level, I think the `Put` monad might not be the most instructive example.

**Edit**

I don't actually need to build a robot or an API like this. The example is completely contrived. I just needed an example where there would never be a reason to pull a value out of the monad. So I'm not asking for the easiest way to solve the robot problem. Rather, this thought experiment about monads without inner values is an attempt to better understand monads generally.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*TL;DR* Monad without its wrapped value isn't very special and you get all the same power modeling it as a list.

There's a thing known as the `Free` monad. It's useful because it in some sense is a good representer for all other monads---if you can understand the behavior of the `Free` monad in some circumstance you have a good insight into how `Monad`s generally will behave there.

It looks like this

```
data Free f a = Pure a
              | Free (f (Free f a))
```

and whenever `f` is a `Functor`, `Free f` is a `Monad`

```
instance Functor f => Monad (Free f) where
  return       = Pure
  Pure a >>= f = f a
  Free w >>= f = Free (fmap (>>= f) w)
```

So what happens when `a` is always `()`? We don't need the `a` parameter anymore

```
data Freed f = Stop 
             | Freed (f (Freed f))
```

Clearly this cannot be a `Monad` anymore as it has the wrong kind (type of types).

```
Monad f ===> f       :: * -> *
             Freed f :: *
```

But we can still define something like `Monad`ic functionality onto it by getting rid of the `a` parts

```
returned :: Freed f
returned = Stop

bound :: Functor f                          -- compare with the Monad definition
   => Freed f -> Freed f                    -- with all `a`s replaced by ()
   -> Freed f
bound Stop k      = k                       Pure () >>= f = f ()
bound (Freed w) k =                         Free w  >>= f =
  Freed (fmap (`bound` k) w)                  Free (fmap (>>= f) w)

-- Also compare with (++)
(++) []     ys = ys
(++) (x:xs) ys = x : ((++) xs ys)
```

Which looks to be (and is!) a `Monoid`.

```
instance Functor f => Monoid (Freed f) where
  mempty  = returned
  mappend = bound
```

And `Monoid`s can be initially modeled by lists. We use the universal property of the list  `Monoid` where if we have a function `Monoid m => (a -> m)` then we can turn a list `[a]` into an `m`.

```
convert :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> [a] -> m
convert f = foldr mappend mempty . map f

convertFreed :: Functor f => [f ()] -> Freed f
convertFreed = convert go where
  go :: Functor f => f () -> Freed f
  go w = Freed (const Stop <$> w)
```

So in the case of your robot, we can get away with just using a list of actions

```
data Direction = Left | Right | Forward | Back
data ActionF a = Move Direction Double a
               | Rotate Double a
               deriving ( Functor )

-- and if we're using `ActionF ()` then we might as well do

data Action = Move Direction Double
            | Rotate Double

robotMovementScript = [ Move Left    10
                      , Move Forward 25
                      , Rotate       180
                      ]
```

Now when we cast it to `IO` we're clearly converting this list of directions into a `Monad` and we can see that as taking our initial `Monoid` and sending it to `Freed` and then treating `Freed f` as `Free f ()` and interpreting that as an initial `Monad` over the `IO` actions we want.

But it's clear that if you're not making use of the "wrapped" values then you're not really making use of `Monad` structure. You might as well just have a list.

Comment: `freed` is exactly the greatest fixed point of a functor.  In other words, `freed f` is just an arbitrary co-inductive data type and has nothing else special about it.

Comment: Well, almost. It's the fixed point of 1 + f---Freed Identity is larger than Fix Identity. And I don't really mean to belabor it, but I tried (and pretty much failed!) to keep the number of tangents to a minimum while stripping down m () to a list.

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to give a partial answer for these parts:

> - Does it make sense to have a monad--such as `RobotMonad`--that never wraps a value? Or is this contrary to the basic concept of monads?
> - Are monoids a better fit for this kind of application? I can imagine concatenating robot control actions with `<>`. Though do notation seems more readable.
> - In the monad's definition, would/could there be something that ensures the type is always `RobotMonad ()`?

The core operation for monads is the monadic bind operation

```
(>>=) :: (Monad m) => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

This means that an action depends (or can depend) on the value of a previous action. So if you have a concept that inherently doesn't sometimes carry something that could be considered as a value (even in a complex form such as the continuation monad), **monad isn't a good abstraction**.

If we abandon `>>=` we're basically left with `Applicative`. It also allows us to compose actions, but their combinations can't depend on the values of preceding ones.

There is also an `Applicative` instance that carries no values, as you suggested: [Data.Functor.Constant](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Constant.html#t%3aConstant). Its actions of type `a` are required to be a monoid so that they can be composed together. This seems like the closest concept to your idea. And of course instead of `Constant` we could use a `Monoid` directly.

---

That said, perhaps simpler solution is to have a monad `RobotMonad a` that does carry a value (which would be essentially isomorphic to the `Writer` monad, as already mentioned). And declare `runRobot` to require `RobotMonad ()`, so it'd be possible to execute only scripts with no value:

```
runRobot :: RobotMonad () -> RobotHandle -> IO ()
```

This would allow you to use the `do` notation and work with values inside the robot script. Even if the robot has no sensors, being able to pass values around can be often useful. And extending the concept would allow you to create a monad transformer such as `RobotMonadT m a` (resembling `WriterT`) with something like

```
runRobotT :: (Monad m) => RobotMonadT m () -> RobotHandle -> IO (m ())
```

or perhaps

```
runRobotT :: (MonadIO m) => RobotMonadT m () -> RobotHandle -> m ()
```

which would be a powerful abstraction that'd allow you to combine robotic actions with an arbitrary monad.

Answer (score 2):

Well there is

```
data Useless a = Useless
instance Monad Useless where
  return = const Useless
  Useless >>= f = Useless
```

but as I indicated, that isn't usefull.

What you want is the `Writer` monad, which wraps up a monoid as a monad so you can use do notation.

Comment: Is the `Writer` monad appropriate for *all* instances where the monad never wraps a value? Or do you just mean it's appropriate for my specific example?

Comment: The `Writer` monad does wrap a value in that `fst . runWriter . return == id`.

Comment: @Jarrett I meant that in your example the "not wrapping a value" part is not usefull (since anything that does this is `Useless`) but that for your example a writer monad is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems like you have a type that supports just

```
(>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b
```

But you further specify that you only want to be able to use `m ()`s. In this case I'd vote for

```
foo = mconcat
      [ moveLeft 10
      , moveForward 25
      , rotate 180]
```

As the simple solution. The alternative is to do something like

```
type Robot = Writer [RobotAction]
inj :: RobotAction -> Robot ()
inj = tell . (:[])

runRobot :: Robot a -> [RobotAction]
runRobot = snd . runWriter

foo = runRobot $ do
  inj $ moveLeft 10
  inj $ moveForward 25
  inj $ rotate 180
```

Using the `Writer` monad.

The problem with not wrapping the value is that

```
return a >>= f === f a
```

So suppose we had some monad that ignored the value, but contained other interesting information,

```
newtype Robot a = Robot {unRobot :: [RobotAction]}

addAction :: RobotAction -> Robot a -> Robot b

f a = Robot [a]
```

Now if we ignore the value,

```
instance Monad Robot where
  return = const (Robot [])
  a >>= f = a -- never run the function
```

Then

```
return a >>= f  /= f a
```

so we don't have a monad. So if you want to the monad to have any interesting states, have `==` return false, then you need to store that value.

Comment: So, is the `Writer` monad the general solution for the type of Monad I described, i.e. where the type is always `SomeMonad ()`?

Comment: @Jarrett No, if that were true than it wouldn't be a monad (think about `return`). Since `return a >>= f` has to be the same as `f a` the monad either has to store the value of `a` somewhere or be constant, neither of which are very interesting